# Divide resulting integer by 1000 in php array

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a query which returns a column as an integer. The result is formatted in milliseconds and I would like to divide it by 1000 to display in seconds.

```
        while ($partsrow = pg_fetch_row($partsresult)) {
          echo "<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>";
          echo "<td> $partsrow[0] </td>";
          echo "<td> $partsrow[1] </td>";
          echo "<td> $partsrow[2] </td>";
          echo "<td>"($partsrow[3]/1000) "</td>";
          echo "<td> $partsrow[4] </td>";
```

This formatting fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably ought to have periods (string concatenation operators) between the parts of the row in question.

```
echo "<td>".($partsrow[3]/1000)."</td>";
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you